# QString::toLongLong() cannot handle big hex numbers

Tags: c++, qt

Qt 5.4.1, Linux 64 bit. A sample code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QString a = "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";
    bool ok;
    qDebug() << a.toLongLong(&ok, 16);
    qDebug() << ok;
    return 0;
}
```

It should display:

```
-1
true
```

but displays:

```
0
false
```

It works fine for smaller numbers.
Why is it so weird? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That value doesn't fit in a signed long long. Try the `toULongLong` method instead.

Comment: It fits - it's how the `-1` is expressed in 64 bits.

Comment: @Googie Wrong. There are more ways to represent negative numbers than just 2's complement. More importantly, the standard explicitly makes signed overflow *undefined.*

Comment: the maximum value for 64-bit signed long long is 0x7fffffffffffffff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the maximum value that can handle a long long is `2^63 - 1`, as it is signed. What you've got here is `2^64 - 1`. That's why it can't parse it.

May be you should try with  `QString::toULongLong`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try
    `a.toULongLong(&ok, 16);` then the result is:

18446744073709551615

true

take a look of the limits http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#limits.h